# Wordpress, IIS 7, web.config, How can I enable caching on the root but disable caching on only the wp-admin folder?

Tags: wordpress, iis, server, web-config

I added the following to `<system.webServer>` in web.config in the root of the WP site and it seems to be working:

```
<system.webServer>
  .....      
  <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="false">
     <profiles>
        <add extension=".php"  policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
     </profiles>
  </caching>
</system.webServer>
```

However, I don't want the wp-admin folder cached, so I added the following to web.config and got a 500 error on the admin interface.  I tried adding this both before the opening `<system.webServer>` and after the closing `</system.webServer>` and got the same result:

```
<location path="wp-admin">
   <system.webServer>
      <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false">
        <profiles>
           <add extension=".php"  policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
        </profiles>
      </caching>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I also tried adding to wp-admin folder a web.config file with the same `<system.webServer>` section as above. That also caused a 500 error.

How can I prevent the wp-admin folder from being cached?  Or is there another better way to prevent the admin dashboard from being cached?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 500.19 error `Configuration Data is invalid`

the more specific error is:

> Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique
>   key attribute 'extension' set to 'php'

Even though the two caching nodes are in different locations, the `wp-admin` location inherits the settings from the root.

The solution is to clear existing entries first and then add the new one.

You should use the <clear/> tag like below:

```
 <location path="wp-admin">
    <system.webServer>
       <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false">
         <profiles>
            <clear/>
            <add extension=".php"  policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
         </profiles>
       </caching>
     </system.webServer>
 </location>
```